# re.sub not replacing the string

Tags: python, regex, string

Is there a mistake in the below code?

```
import re
text = 'AFL_v_CalcOneIntAreas (%as_Points[0].ub_X%);\n'

print(re.sub('as_Points[0].ub_X', '0x00', text))
```

The expected output is

```
AFL_v_CalcOneIntAreas (%0x00%);
```

but the actual output is same as input string, please let me know why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols `[` and `]` means something in regular expressions, you have to escape them:

```
>>> re.sub('as_Points\[0\]\.ub_X', '0x00', text)
'AFL_v_CalcOneIntAreas (%0x00%);\n'
```

`[a-z]` represents all the lower letters for instance. `[...]` are used to denote «anything in them» so `[01]` is for 0 or 1.
In your case `'as_Points[0].ub_X'` is in fact `'as_Points0.ub_X'`.

Note that the `.` has special meanings too. It means 1 character. You should also escape it too.

---

If you don't know if your expression contains characters you should escape, you can use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
>>> someExpression = "as_Points[0].ub_X"
>>> re.escape(someExpression)
'as\\_Points\\[0\\]\\.ub\\_X'
>>> re.sub(re.escape(someExpression), '0x00', text)
'AFL_v_CalcOneIntAreas (%0x00%);\n'
```

But if you don't need regular expression power, strings have the replace method:

```
text.replace('as_Points[0].ub_X','0x00')
```

Comment: Suppose the search string is stored in a variable and I dont know the position of '[' or ']' in variable, is there any other raw string mechanism that accomplish the same?

Comment: @Bharadwaj I have updated my answer. You can use the `re.escape` function.

Answer (score 3):

You should escape `[`, `]` and `.`:

```
>>> re.sub('as_Points\[0\]\.ub_X', '0x00', text)
```

`.` means "any character", `[0]` matches only "0".

You can do this as well:

```
esc = re.escape('as_Points[0].ub_X')  # now '[0]' is treated like the string
                                      # literal '[0]' and not the regex '[0]'
re.sub(esc, '0x00', text)
```

Visit the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more useful functions.

Comment: Suppose the search string is stored in a variable and I dont know the position of '[' or ']' in variable, is there any other raw string mechanism that accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2):

Your searching for special characters in your regex. You have to escape them.

```
text = 'AFL_v_CalcOneIntAreas (%as_Points[0].ub_X%);\n'
print(re.sub('as_Points\[0\]\.ub_X', '0x00', text))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using regular expressions you need to escape characters like `[]` with backslashes, because they have special meanings.

But you don't need to use regular expressions to replace a literal string. Just use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html):

```
print(text.replace('as_Points[0].ub_X','0x00'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `[` and `]` and the dot `.`:

```
print(re.sub('as_Points\[0\]\.ub_X', '0x00', text))
# prints: AFL_v_CalcOneIntAreas (%0x00%);
```

Comment: Your forgot to escape the . too

Comment: @Dotcomsuperstar In this example it does not matter, but good catch. thx.

Comment: @Marcin Why is \. not important in this case? isn't even the . spl character in re?

Comment: it is special. but in this case .  will match any character, not only dot. this wont change this particular example. but in general, its better to escape it off course.